Prove that sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is not convergent.
The standard branch of logarithm, $\log:\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\to\mathbb{C}$ is defined as
$$
\log(z):=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)\tag{2}
$$
where $\arg(z)$ is the standard branch of the argument, defined as the unique argument in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.
For $n\geq 1$, define $$a_n:= \frac{1}{\pi}\Im(\log (1-e^{2\pi i b_n}))$$ where $b_n=(2e)^n-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\Im(s)$ denotes the imaginary part of $s$.

I need to prove that sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is not convergent, given that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{b_n\} \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

We prove by contradiction. Let us assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=l$ then we have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{n\to\infty} (\log (1-e^{2\pi i b_n})-\log (1-e^{-2\pi i b_n})) =l $$
So we obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\log (1-e^{2\pi i b_n})-\log (1-e^{-2\pi i b_n})) =2\pi il $$
So taking exponential and using continuity of $e^z$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{(\log (1-e^{2\pi i b_n})-\log (1-e^{-2\pi i b_n}))} =e^{2\pi il} $$
Therefore we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{\log (1-e^{2\pi i b_n})}}{e^{\log (1-e^{-2\pi i b_n})}}=e^{2\pi il} $$
Hence we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-e^{2\pi i b_n}}{1-e^{-2\pi i b_n}}=e^{2\pi il} $$
On simplification we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-e^{2\pi i b_n})=e^{2\pi il} $$
So we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i b_n}=-e^{2\pi il} $$
Hence we obtain
So we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i b_n}=e^{2\pi il+\pi i} $$
Also $b_n=(2e)^n-\frac{1}{n}$, so we have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty$$
I am not able to calculate after this. Any guidance please. Thank you!
Edit: We are given given that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{b_n\} \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

The problem is equivalent to showing that for every $N > 0$ there exist $n_1,n_2 > N$, and $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $k_1 < b_{n_1} < k_1 + 1/2$ and $k_2 - 1/2 < b_{n_2} < k_2$ (so regardless of how much times passes there exists a $b_{n_1}$ which has decimal part < 1/2 and a $b_{n_2}$ which has decimal part > 1/2).

No: this wouldn't prevent the fractional part of $b_n$ to tend to $\frac12$.

@AnneBauval Can you please show that thw only possible case for convergence is when fractional part of $b_n$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$.

@AnneBauval  We have $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i b_n}=-e^{2\pi il} $ where $l=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. So why is the case $a_n$ converges to $1/2$ and fractional part of $b_n$ converges to $1$ not possible?

If @zetko's conjecture holds (i.e. if the fractional part ${b_n}\in(0,1)$ has a subsequence in $(0,1/2)$ and another one in $(1/2,1)$), then (obviously!) its only possible limit is $1/2$. My really not deep comment was only to stress that this condition would not be sufficient for divergence. Note that moreover, it is neither necessary. Anyway, this condition is unproved, and I agree with you that if it is not fulfilled $a_n$ can as well converge to $1/2$ and ${b_n}$ to $1$. For all these reasons, I downvoted that (essentially empty) "answer".

Note that in your post, instead of taking the exponential, you could as well write directly:
$$\pi a_n=\arg(1-e^{2i\pi b_n})=\arg(-e^{i\pi b_n}2i\sin(\pi b_n))=\arg(e^{i\pi(b_n-1/2)}(-1)^{\lfloor b_n\rfloor})=\arg(e^{i\pi({b_n}-1/2)})$$ hence $$a_n={b_n}-1/2.$$ Btw, how do you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {b_n} \neq \frac{1}{2}$?

@Max:  As $\frac1n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty0}$ the behavior of the sequence $b_n$ is driven by $(2e)^n$. It is known that for (Lebesgue) almost all $\alpha>1$, $\alpha^n$ is uniformly distributed $\mod1$ (ud1), however not a single example of such $\alpha>1$ is known (It is a very hard problem, many mathematicians play with $(3/2)^n$ for theoretical reasons). Anyway, to prove that $(2e)^n$ has at least two different limit points probably one has to look at $$2^n\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

I was also looking at this theorem  yesterday (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html) but didn't mention it here since it was of no use. Max, $(2e)^n\to\infty$. It is its fractional part which must be proved to have 2 limit points.

@AnneBauval Thank you so much for the link. It is very useful. Highly appreciated. Thanks.

Don't thank me: as I said, I don't find it useful. It doesn't help at all to solve your problem. I only provided it because it was related to (the interesting but useless part of) Mitten's comment.

@AnneBauval Oh I see. But why? The link is connected with Mittens idea

Where does your problem come from? And again: how do you know that lim{bn}≠1/2
?

@AnneBauval Actually my Professor gave me this problem. I was not sure about the limit part. At some point of time I was about to claim that the limit is not equal to $1/2$.

Note, this is not a full solution. For any angle $\theta \in (-2\pi, 2\pi)$ the following holds (you can prove it via geometry):
$$
1-e^{i\theta}=
\begin{cases}
Ae^{i\frac{\theta-\pi}{2}} & \theta\in(0,2\pi) \\
Ae^{i\frac{\theta+\pi}{2}} & \theta\in(-2\pi,0) \\
0 & \theta=0
\end{cases},
$$ for some $A>0$.
Let $\hat{\theta}$ denote the argument of $e^{i\theta}$, then
$$\Im \log(1-e^{i\theta}) = \arg (1 - e^{i\theta}) = \arg (1 - e^{i\hat{\theta}}) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\hat{\theta}-\pi}{2} & \hat{\theta} \in (0,\pi) \\
\frac{\hat{\theta}+\pi}{2} & \hat{\theta} \in (-\pi,0) \\
0 & \hat{\theta} = 0
\end{cases}.$$
So for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

if $0 + 2k\pi< \theta < \pi + 2k\pi$ then $\Im \log(1-e^{i\theta}) = \frac{\hat{\theta}-\pi}{2} <  0$;
if $-\pi + 2k\pi< \theta < 2k\pi$ then $\Im \log(1-e^{i\theta}) = \frac{\hat{\theta}+\pi}{2} >0$.

By plugging in $\theta = 2\pi b_n$ and dividing by $2\pi$ we get:

if $k < b_n < 1/2 + k$, then $\pi a_n < 0$ (the fractional part of $b_n < 1/2$);
if $k - 1/2 < b_n < k$, then $\pi a_n > 0$ (the fractional part of $b_n > 1/2$).

If we show that for each $N > 0$, both of these options apperar for some $n_1,n_2 > N$, then the only option left to consider is that $a_n$ converges to $0$ (the fractional part of $b_n$ converges to 1/2 as @AnneBauval pointed out). If you can further disprove this option then the sequence diverges.

Thanks. ($+1$) How is the only option left is that $a_n$ converges to $0$? What about $a_n$ converging to a value grater than $0$? I know you have written the explaination in your answer. I need further elaboration please. Thank you.

We have $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i b_n}=-e^{2\pi il} $ where $l=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. So why is the case $a_n$ converges to $1/2$ and fractional part of $b_n$ converges to $1$ not possible?

@zetko: your solution is kind of circular. The key is to understand the dynamics of the sequence $b_n-\frac12\mod1$. Furthermore, as $\frac1n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and $t\mapsto t-\lfloor t\rfloor -\frac12$ is continuous 1-periodic, understanding the set of limit points of $(2e)^n-\lfloor (2e)^n\rfloor$ is the key. I think one has to look at the expression $2^n\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}$.
